# How to use a SharePoint calendar within Thunderbird Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, lightning, sharepoint-2010, thunderbird-addon

I'm using Thunderbird with the Lightning add-on (current version) and want to show a calendar provided by MS SharePoint 2010.

I couldn't find any Add-Ons or useful information so far, and natively it doesn't seem to be supported.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: I use this [exchangecalendar](https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar) addon for Exchange calendars, but I can't get it to work with Sharepoint calendars.  I know that doesn't help other than to show there might be some undocumented projects out there that actually work.

Comment: Yes, I use the same addon for Exchange, too. But unfortunately not usable for sharepoint.

Comment: Dang, hope you find something.  Please post back if you do so that SE will alert me.

Comment: Any news on this subject? Thx